# Whats the best way to show current time in Live wallpaper Using andengine?

Tags: android, performance, andengine

I am trying to display current time in my live wallpaper.
I am using andengine gles2 anchor center to develop it.
What i have done is

Registered an update handler with scene and **Using Calendar instance read current time and displayed it.But it makes continues GC runs .** Here is my code

```
    mScene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

            c = Calendar.getInstance();
            yy = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mm = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            dd = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            hh = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            amOrpm = c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
            am_pm = "AM";
            if (amOrpm == 1) {
                am_pm = "PM";
            } else {
                am_pm = "AM";
            }
            displayString = hh + "\n" + min + "\n " + am_pm;
            mText.setText(String.valueOf(displayString));
        }

        @Override
        public void reset() {
        }
    });
```

What is the method I have to follow to decrease Garbage collectors running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Time`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html) object. You can create a single `Time`-instance and update it with its [`setToNow()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#setToNow%28%29)-method. Then you can acces the YEAR, MONTH etc. from the `year`, `month` etc. fields (they update when you call the `setToNow()` method).

Since this is not creating any new instances of the relatively heavy `Calendar` every update, you'll experience much fewer garbage collections.